# Azure AD AcquireTokenOnBehalfOfAsync Getting Error AADSTS50013

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

AADSTS50013
I am trying to get Token on Behalf of a User. But I am getting this error.
: The token issuer doesn't match the api version: A version 1 token cannot be used with the v2 endpoint.

Couldn't find much help, any article or Sample solution.

Comment: This is pretty obvious - you cannot use v1 token with v2 endpoint. can you paste your configuration (omitting client secret), the endpoints used and the JWT token you present as assertion for the on-behalf-of flow.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD has versioned it's service and today there are 2 production endpoints you can use (coined v1, v2). The notable difference is the following

#### v1.0 (ADAL libraries)

- Supports Azure AD accounts only.
- Supports static consent (register permissions, user must consent to all of them even if they don't necessarily require them).
- More customized version of OAuth2.0 and OpenId Connect.
- Register your app at https://portal.azure.com.

#### v2.0 (MSAL libraries)

- Supports Azure AD, Microsoft Accounts, and Azure AD B2C.
- Supports static and dynamic (also called incremental) consent. Ask for consent as your app needs the,.
- Works with Open Source libraries.
- Register your app at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com.

The error comes from registering a v1 or v2 app, and then requesting a token from a different endpoint.  You'll want to make sure to line up the versions using the reference above. Checkout the [on-behalf-of sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof) and follow those steps to ensure consistency.